# jssc connector. Detect unknown port on notebook. Open and close operation takes long time

Tags: serial-port, device, jssc

I have a problem because I use in my application jssc(java-simple-serial-connector) and find availible ports using that code:

```
String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
```

and as a result i get port name "COM3". The problem is I develop this application on notebook and this notebook(looking at device manager) has not installed any COM(rs232) ports. So the question is why it detect port "COM3"?

[image: Here is my device manager screen:]

The next thing is that when I try to open this port and than close it i takes about 1.2 second. Is it typical time for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your hardware, this is most likely the Intel 
[Intel Active Management Technology serial over LAN feature](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-amt-serial-over-lan-to-the-fullest). I have a couple of motherboards that support it but have never had a need for it. Anyways, just go out and buy a USB to TTL UART cable. There are so many to choose from but I have good result with this one

[http://www.amazon.com/PL2303HX-RS232-Cable-Module-Converter/dp/B008AGDTA4/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1405789976&sr=8-7&keywords=usb+serial+cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008AGDTA4)

Since this is a laptop and it doesn't sounds like you have a real DB9 port, buying a USB UART cable is your best bet. Now, if you just want to play with jSSC feel free to try COM0COM. I use jSSC and COM0COM for testing work project without issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the problem is why it detect com port not how to get this port on notebook. I have USB to DB9 converter and it works perfectly but when I disconnect this I want that my code doesn't detect any ports. My notebook is MSI gx740

Comment: Could be a bunch of reasons. If the OS can see a port, then jSSC or any other serial library will see it. I still think that the Intel AMT is a good possibility (see my first link). As a test, you could install a serial console program and see what ports it lists.